# Moving Chart Div Names to outside Bars

Tags: html, css

Writing a HTML bar chart. Currently the names / labels of the Divs/ Bars are appearing inside the bars. Is there a way I could get them to appear outside of the bars tagged to the left end of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.chart div {
  font: 10px Ubuntu;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  clear:both;
}

</style>
<div class="chart">
<div style="width:0px;">Inwood 10</div>
<div style="width:3px;">Washington Heights 111</div>
<div style="width:7px;">Hamilton Heights 230</div>
<div style="width:10px;">Chinatown 314</div>
<div style="width:10px;">East Harlem 346</div>
<div style="width:16px;">Harlem 514</div>
<div style="width:18px;">Morningside Heights 590</div>
<div style="width:24px;">Battery Park 804</div>
<div style="width:25px;">Little Italy 814</div>
<div style="width:25px;">Yorkville 841</div>
<div style="width:33px;">North Sutton Area 1088</div>
<div style="width:37px;">Carnegie Hill 1228</div>
<div style="width:47px;">Tribeca 1544</div>
<div style="width:50px;">Central Park 1654</div>
<div style="width:51px;">Financial District 1684</div>
<div style="width:62px;">Lower East Side 2050</div>
<div style="width:64px;">Soho 2112</div>
<div style="width:71px;">West Village 2333</div>
<div style="width:89px;">Murray Hill 2932</div>
<div style="width:110px;">East Village 3642</div>
<div style="width:117px;">Clinton 3873</div>
<div style="width:137px;">Greenwich Village 4511</div>
<div style="width:140px;">Garment District 4614</div>
<div style="width:189px;">Chelsea 6225</div>
<div style="width:229px;">Gramercy 7568</div>
<div style="width:297px;">Upper West Side 9808</div>
<div style="width:428px;">Upper East Side 14113</div>
<div style="width:439px;">Midtown 14490</div>


</div>
```

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYaYq.jpg)

[How i would like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G5MP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the text in another <"div"> and float it to the left of the bar. Its the only way i'm thinking of, but i'm also kind of new. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can move the text outside the containing element. What you should do is to create separate elements (divs for example) for the label and bar itself. The bar div could be contained inside the label's div. Something like this:

```
<div>
  Label
  <div style="width:123px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample how you can make to work it. I am not the CSS wiz but  I guess this might be a good starting point. Run the code snippet to see the result

```css
.chart div {
  font: 10px Ubuntu;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
.chart div span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="chart">
  <div style="width:0px;"><span>Inwood</span> 10</div>
  <div style="width:3px;"><span>Washington Heights</span> 111</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks very much for taking the time to comment. I've given it a go and works for the first few bars but ends up overlapping as shown in the attached picture. http://i.imgur.com/LIAzeVL.png